# Why can you create new tags, but not their descriptions, at 1500?

Tags: feature-request, tag-wiki, tag-creation

Sorry, but my curiosity got the better of me. I have to know!

What is the rationale behind giving people with a reputation of 1500 the ability to create new tags, but not descriptions for the tags?
I would have thought that "create a new tag" and "enter a description for said tag" would go together. But no, you need 5000 rep for the latter. Why?

Unless there's a good reason, that I missed, I would suggest making the required reputations for the two the same.

Comment: are you aware that one can suggest tag descriptions at reputation lower than 1500? these suggestions are like _description creation_, except for these pass through review

Answer (score 6):

The reason is peer review.

Tag descriptions don't get bumped to the 
main page and nobody gets to see 'em.

ALL content is supposed to be peer-reviewed, that   s why we don't have a minor-edit feature. First off, 1.5k is easy, and you don't want a user to put random crap/spam in a tag excerpt. How would *you* feel if, while typing in the tag box, a suggestion with a rather offensive excerpt came up? You'd think SO itself had put it there, it has no indication that it's entered by a lowly user (unlike posts, where if you see something wrong, it's obvious that it's not SO's fault but that of the user). Well, a newbie would feel that.

I *think* that even 5k users have to go through approval for tag descriptions. They can't approve their own edits. <s>(If you have a high score on the tag, you can)</s>. This is due to the same reason as above--5k ain't too hard to get, and tagwikis can lead to scary situations.

On the other hand, tags are shown on the post, and *someone* will notice if you create a bad tag.

When you think about it, almost all such restrictions are due to peer review.

Tagwikis get reviewed pretty quickly, so you really don't have to worry.